# Rerun the code if error occurs

Tags: python, python-3

I am fairly new to coding so please bear with me. I am using random.choice for my code to run.
So, sometimes it gives me an error 'Cannot choose from an empty sequence' and sometimes it does not.
Now, what I want is that, I want to have a way ( maybe an if statement) which says
if 'error occurs'
then rerun the whole code.
So, this way I would end up not getting an error as it would rerun until I do not get an error.
I am not sure if this is even possible in python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for problems specific to the Pi, not general Python/programming questions.  I suggest you work through some Python tutorials.

Comment: Search up Python exception handling...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it is hard to give a specific answer, but I can *try* for a general one. (that try was a bad pun as we will see).

What you need here is a [try except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) block. Basically, you can tell Python if it comes to an error, to do something. In this case, we will tell it to do nothing and wrap the whole thing in a while loop.

```
from random import choice


# Keep doing this loop until we hit break.
while True:

    # Some stuff happens here that may or may not populate your list.

    try:
        var = choice(the_list) # This is the part that has been breaking your code.
        break # If the above succeeds, we break here
    except IndexError:
        # If there is an IndexError (the type you are having), wait a second then 
        # the loop will repeat.
        sleep(1) 

# Do stuff with var.
```

That is your general answer based on what you asked. How I would approach this is a bit simpler and more elegant I think.

```
from random import choice
from time import sleep

the_list = []

while not the_list:
    # Try to get the list information
    sleep(1) # Just so we aren't doing this over and over redundantly.

var = choice(the_list)
# Do stuff with var.
```

Hope this helps!